# Google Analytics Event Tracking Code issue

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm using the new `analytics.js` on my site. I have added the following event tracking code to my callback function of the signup form to track user signups on GA. I see Pageviews, but not the events in the Behaviour.

```
$.post("http://example.com/user/signup",
    JSON.stringify({
        email: emailInput,
    }),
    function(data,status){
       ga('send', 'event', 'user', 'try', 'apply-now', emailInput, {});
       fbq('track', 'Lead');
    }
);
```

I even see a request goes to GA with the followings as params,

```
ec:user
ea:try
el:apply-now
```

The tracking code mentioned below the GA for the facebook works fine.
This is my site.http://www.maturify.com/commercial.html

Comment: Have you had a look at the "Real-Time / Events" report? Are them missing from there also?

Comment: It shows the user, but not the events...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think emailInput variable will contain a string of email address, and fourth parameter is **ev** EventValue which is required as positive integer value in google analytics.